# What's the full syntax of CKEDITOR.addTemplates()?

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I wasn't able to find any documentation on this one. 
Can I somehow create multiple sets of templates in my template plugin (f.e first you choose a template, then you choose color scheme for the chosen template)?
Right now in /templates/templates/default.js I have something lile^

```
CKEDITOR.addTemplates("default",{imagesPath:CKEDITOR.getUrl(CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath("templates")+"templates/images/"),templates:[ /* list of my custom templates */ ]});
```

What does the first `"default"` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there's no documentation for the "addTemplates"-method for CKEditor 4, but there is for CKEditor 3. I'm not sure which version of CKEditor you're currently in?

Here's a snippet from the CKEditor 3 documentation:

```
// Register a template definition set named "default".
CKEDITOR.addTemplates( 'default',
{
    // The name of the subfolder that contains the preview images of the templates.
    imagesPath : CKEDITOR.getUrl( CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath( 'templates' ) + 'templates/images/' ),

    // Template definitions.
    templates :
        [
            {
                title: 'My Template 1',
                image: 'template1.gif',
                description: 'Description of My Template 1.',
                html:
                    '<h2>Template 1</h2>' +
                    '<p><img src="/logo.png" style="float:left" />Type your text here.</p>'
            },
            {
                title: 'My Template 2',
                html:
                    '<h3>Template 2</h3>' +
                    '<p>Type your text here.</p>'
            }
        ]
});
```

Full documentation:
https://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Templates

Comment: I currently use CKEditor 4.4.1. Thank you for the snippet.
It seems "default" is a set's name and I can add multiple sets in plugin.js
Reference: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.templates

Comment: @E.Sereda - very well, then I'm afraid I can't be of much help, as you're right about there not being any documentation on the addTemplates-method in CKEditor 4.X, but the method might be similar, so you should try out the snippet :-D

Comment: Hope so. I'll be right back after attempting to do this.